# Can an extension modify the preprocessor variables used during the build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, preprocessor-directive

E.g. I'd like the extension to do the equivalent of:

```
if (this_is_my_machine)
{
    #undef DEBUG
}
```

This would involve the extension modifying the CSC command lines used for all or certain projects during the Visual Studio build process. I suppose that's what I'd like to know if it can be done.

Comment: Why not just change the build configuration that you are using?

Comment: I want the extension to analyse the build environment versus having a build configuration for every conceivable environment.

Comment: how do you determine 'this_is_my_machine'?

Comment: That is only an example, but maybe by machine name?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this through an extension. (Ignore the details for a moment that you really can't, or at least not in a way that's useful to you.) The standard thought experiment question is "what happens if build outside Visual Studio?" Think continuous integration machines, or me simply being lazy and typing msbuild on a command line.

In the project file, you can always add something like:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ComputerName)' == 'MY-COMPUTER-NAME'">
    <DefineConstants>SPECIAL_BUILD_MACHINE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Put that after other property groups since the file is evaluated top down.

Comment: Then I could use the extension to modify the project file pre-build, thanks.

Comment: No, no no no no. That breaks source control and a whole host of other things. Don't do that.

Comment: If I check the change in pre-build, I could mark it as such a change, to be ignored in normal change reports.